# Flex + Blazeds + remoting

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

I recently started working on a project which requires me to have an expertise with Flex and BlazeDS with remoting technologies like AMF...I have been a java programmer all this while and I do not have any understanding of how Flex and java work together. 
I have tried setting up project on my machine @ home w blazeDS turnkey and a sample project . but could not get started. I was using eclipse indigo + Flex 3 SDK.they are not compatible.

I am not sure on how to make things work.

Please let me know if there are good tutorials./ any material I could refer to get acquainted w flex.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest , rather than asking a question for something as huge as this, you google, go through the articles you get on livedocs (adobe provides a lot of articles on using Flex with Webservices and Remote Objects) and then get back incase you have issues following the articles there.

Comment: Though in a nutshell, Flex uses Java RMI (Remote Method Invocation) and the objects on the JVM of the server then reply back using some Remote Method Invocation technique.You need not worry about the implementation as the API for doing this is pretty solid and has documentation all over the web.

Comment: let my google that for you , here is a good result to get started http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a huge amount of advice to offer, I've done some flex with Java but not BlazeDS, I just created web services on the Java side and bound them to the Flex client. This is probably not the most efficient way to do things but you might consider it as it alternative to Blaze if you have the choice.

For general information on Flex/Java, James Ward is well worth following, here's his blog:

http://www.jamesward.com/flex-and-java-resources

The O' Reilly book "Enterprise Development with Flex" might cover what you need but I haven't read this so I can't recommend it one way or the other.

Regarding eclipse Indigo with Flex, if you're having problems with this combination then maybe just forget about the eclipse plugin and download Flashbuilder as a standalone application. This means that you'll have two copies of eclipse installed (the one you got from Adobe with the Flex plugin pre-integrated and your own eclipse install for non Flex development). It's a bit wasteful but probably more efficient than trying to pin down the source of the problems between Flex and Indigo.